# Execute zgrep command and write results to a file

Tags: python, file, shell, command, subprocess

I have a folder containing lots of files like `file_1.gz` to `file_250.gz` and increasing.

A `zgrep` command which searches through them is like:

```
zgrep -Pi "\"name\": \"bob\"" ../../LM/DATA/file_*.gz
```

I want to execute this command in a python subprocess like:

```
out_file = os.path.join(out_file_path, file_name)
search_command = ['zgrep', '-Pi', '"name": "bob"', '../../LM/DATA/file_*.gz']
process = subprocess.Popen(search_command, stdout=out_file)
```

The problem is the `out_file` is created but it is empty and these errors are raised:

```
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>
'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

What is the solution?

Comment: And do you really need use `subprocess` here? Why don't just use `os.walk()` to get all files in that folder, and use regex to search the files that you want?

Comment: Actually, if the point is to run the same command for all the files, there is no need for python at all. `find ../../LM/DATA -name 'file*.gz' | xargs zgrep -Pi '"name": "bob"'`. And if the point is to run it in parallel, just use `GNU parallel` instead of `xargs`.

Comment: The reason is to this peace of code is part of a big project that searches  through log files and then returns the results to a client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a file object:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(search_command, stdout=open(out_file, 'w'))
```

Citing the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), emphasis mine:

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are **PIPE**, an **existing file descriptor** (a positive integer), an **existing file object**, and **None**. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.

Combined with LFJ's answer -  using the convenience functions is recommended, and you need to use `shell=True` to make the wildcard (`*`) work:

`subprocess.call(' '.join(search_command), stdout=open(out_file, 'w'), shell=True)`

Or when you're using shell anyways, you can use the shell redirection as well:

`subprocess.call("%s > %s" % (' '.join(search_command), out_file), shell=True)`

Comment: So what about `process = subprocess.Popen(search_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE; out_file = process.stdout`?

Comment: And what should this effectively do? The same as `stdout=None`?

Comment: This will save the command output into `process.stdout`, if without `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` then `process.stdout` will be empty. You could try them and see what's the different.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs anything saved in `process.stdout`. In my understanding he was trying to save the results of each run into `out_file`.

Comment: Well, I've check the question again and maybe you're right :)

Comment: when i use the `process = subprocess.Popen(search_command, stdout=open(out_file, 'w'))` command I get error **gzip: ../../LM/DATA/file_*.gz: No such file or directory** @liborm

Comment: there is no need to use `shell=True` here. [Use `glob.glob()` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33454098/4279)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. you should pass something with a valid `.fileno()` method instead of the filename
2. the shell expands `*` but subprocess does not invoke the shell unless you ask. You could use `glob.glob()` to expand the file patterns manually.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from glob import glob
from subprocess import check_call

search_command = ['zgrep', '-Pi', '"name": "bob"'] 
out_path = os.path.join(out_file_path, file_name)
with open(out_path, 'wb', 0) as out_file:
    check_call(search_command + glob('../../LM/DATA/file_*.gz'), 
               stdout=out_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your want to execute a shell command and get the output, try to  use `subprocess.check_output()`. it is very simple, and you could save the output to a file easily.

```
command_output = subprocess.check_output(your_search_command, shell=True)
with open(out_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write(command_output)
```

Comment: there is no need to load the whole output into memory only to write to a file immediately. [Pass the file object as `stdout` parameter instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33454098/4279)

Answer (score 0):

My problem consist of two parts:

1. First part is answered by @liborm as well
2. The second part is related to the files that zgrep tries to search in. when we write a command like **zgrep "pattern" path/to/files/*.gz** the bash automatically removes the ***.gz** by all files ends with .gz. When i run the command in a subprocess no one replaced the ***.gz** by real file, in consequence the error **gzip: ../../LM/DATA/file_*.gz: No such file or directory** raises. So solved it by:

   ```
   for file in os.listdir(archive_files_path):
       if file.endswith(".gz"):
           search_command.append(os.path.join(archive_files_path, file))
   ```